# How to change data type of a column in an SQL table from integer to decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, integer, decimal, type-conversion

I have assigned the data type of one of the columns of a table I have created as `int`. My problem is that it is not showing decimal places when I run a query against it.

How do I correct the data type of this column so that it accepts decimal places?

Table is `dbo.Budget` and the column concerned is called `ROE`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Easy - just run this SQL statement

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Budget
ALTER COLUMN ROE DECIMAL(20,2)   -- or whatever precision and scale you need.....
```

See the [**freely available** MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx) on what exactly the precision, scale and length in decimal numbers are and what ranges of values are possible

Comment: Be careful: if you had `NOT NULL` on that column, you need to specify it also in alter statement, otherwise it would accept nulls now

Comment: how to set default value with alter statement?

Comment: @JitendraPancholi: your best resource is **always** the [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) on these things ....

Answer (score 3):

You can execute this simple sql statement

```
Alter table yourtable
Alter Column yourtable_column Decimal(10,2)
```

you can set decimal precision and scale whatever you need.

Answer (score 3):

Just to have this stated clearly:

If there is no data in the table, or not that much, then the simple `ALTER TABLE` statement (as described in the other answers here) is fine.

But, if there is a lot of data (millions of rows, or possibly less depending on the size of the table) and/or a lot of contention on the table and not much opportunity for a full downtime / maintenance window, then it requires a different approach, such as what I described in this answer: [Narrowing the Data Types on a very large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114565/narrowing-the-data-types-on-a-very-large-table/27119522#27119522).

Answer (score 1):

Alter datatype of that column ..But In general sql wont allow to channge.It will prompt u drop that column..There is setting to achive that thing.
Go to Tool-Option-designers-Table and Database designers and Uncheck Prevent saving option.I m taking abt sql server 2008R2[image]